# How to detect that a function is already inside a function having that same name

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like this; problem is  (typeof myfunc == 'function') is always true since it is the same function name. Is it possible to exclude that self name function from the scope of typeof somehow ?

```
function myfunc() { 
    alert('old');       
}

function myfunc() { 
    if (typeof myfunc == 'function') {      
        // alert('old');        
        alert('new');
    } else {
        alert('myfunc does not exist');
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, well, the second function completely overwrites the first one, as two functions can't have the same name, so basically you only have one function, the last one, problem solved, gold star to me ?

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: That's not even what `typeof` does. Why not try `myfunc == otherfunc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. You would need to first capture the function, before you override it.

```
var _orgFnc = window.myfunc;  //assuming it is global
function myfunc() { 
    if (_orgFnc) {      
        // alert('old');        
        alert('new');
    } else {
        alert('myfunc does not exist');
    }
}
```

if it is not global you would need to basically do

```
var _orgFnc = (typeof myfunc === "function") ? myfunc : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that

```
function myfunc() { } // first definition
function myfunc() { } // second definition
```

is essentially the same as

```
var myfunc;
myfunc = (function() { }); // first definition
myfunc = (function() { }); // second definition
```

You can see here that the name `myfunc` exists and refers to a function object.  The first definition no longer exists since the second has replaced it.

The closest you could come, I think, is to use function expressions and test for existence before (re)defining the function.

```
var myfunc;
myfunc = (function() { });
if (typeof myfunc === 'function') { 
    alert("Function exists"); 
} else {
    alert("Did not exist, create (new) definition now");
    myfunc = (function() { });
}
```